# How do I verify that multiple users fulfill the requirements of their input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a game for unlimited amount of players. Each player will take a guess of 5 numbers between 1 and 25. (And some more requirements you will see down in the code) My issue is that I want the first user to input his guess, if his guess fullfills the requirements we go back and iterate through the name list for the next players guess. The problem is I don't know how to break out of the loops and get back to the "main" loop and get the next player. Thankful for suggestions on this problem!

```
while True:
        try:
            for name in name_list:
                guess = input("{}, Enter 5 numbers between 1 and 25 (Seperate with ','): ".format(name))
                guess = guess.split(",")
                guess = [int(i) for i in guess]

                while True:
                    for i in guess:
                        if len(guess) != 5:
                            print("You need to enter 5 numbers")
                            guess = input("{}, Enter 5 numbers between 1 and 25 (Seperate with ','): ".format(name))
                            guess = guess.split(",")
                            guess = [int(i) for i in guess]

                        elif guess.count(i) > 1:
                            print("There can only be one of each number!")
                            guess = input("{}, Enter 5 numbers between 1 and 25 (Seperate with ','): ".format(name))
                            guess = guess.split(",")
                            guess = [int(i) for i in guess]

                        elif i > 25 or i < 1:
                            print("The numbers need to be between 1 and 25")
                            guess = input("{}, Enter 5 numbers between 1 and 25 (Seperate with ','): ".format(name))
                            guess = guess.split(",")
                            guess = [int(i) for i in guess]
                else:
                    break


            guess_list.append(guess)
            print("Your numbers: " + str(guess) + "\n")


        except ValueError:
            print("You need to enter integers and seperate by (',')")
            continue
´´´
```

Comment: `break` will only break out of the inner most loop when it's called. If you want to break out of multiple loops (like both the `for` loop and inner `while` loop, you will need to set a variable to true and call break in both loops if it is true. See this [link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue) if you're unfamiliar with break.

Comment: Thanks for responding! How would you set it up to loop it the right way? I've been trying a few different ways, doesnt work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone through your code and there are a couple of breaking problems with it. I've put a quick summary of them, as well as a (I think) correct version of what you're trying to do.

You're checking `len(guess)` inside a loop of it, you should check the length once before checking each of the elements

To your original question, have a look at the `input_good` variable which is set to true in the for loop and to False if anything is wrong... This variable will let the inner while loop know to break out of itself when everything is good (since we can only directly break one loop at a time)

This is a starting point, next you should look at using functions to handle repetitive behaviour, and putting `try/except` around as little code as possible (bad practice to have catch anywhere error handling)

```
# list of names so it runs
name_list = ['Matthew', 'Luke', 'Mark', 'John']

while True:
    try:
        for name in name_list:
            guess = input("{}, Enter 5 numbers between 1 and 25 (Seperate with ','): ".format(name))
            guess = guess.split(",")
            guess = [int(i) for i in guess]

            while True:
                # This if is on the whole list, so it shouldn't be inside the enumeration
                if len(guess) != 5:
                    print("You need to enter 5 numbers")
                    guess = input("{}, Enter 5 numbers between 1 and 25 (Seperate with ','): ".format(name))
                    guess = guess.split(",")
                    guess = [int(i) for i in guess]
                    # continue will cause the while loop to run again,
                    # causing this if statemtn to run again with the new guess numbers
                    continue

                for i in guess:
                    # We need to break out of 2 loops now...
                    # So we set a flag that the outer loop will check and break if the input is good
                    input_good = True
                    if guess.count(i) > 1:
                        print("There can only be one of each number!")
                        guess = input("{}, Enter 5 numbers between 1 and 25 (Seperate with ','): ".format(name))
                        guess = guess.split(",")
                        guess = [int(i) for i in guess]
                        input_good = False
                        # input good False means the outer loop won't break,
                        # but we still want to break out of the for loop and back into the while loop
                        break

                    elif i > 25 or i < 1:
                        print("The numbers need to be between 1 and 25")
                        guess = input("{}, Enter 5 numbers between 1 and 25 (Seperate with ','): ".format(name))
                        guess = guess.split(",")
                        guess = [int(i) for i in guess]
                        input_good = False
                        break # as above
                print('run %s' % str(input_good))
                if input_good:
                    break
            # This else break does nothing as it is only hit when the loop condition is false and while True is always true
            #else:
            #    break
        guess_list.append(guess)
        print("Your numbers: " + str(guess) + "\n")


    except ValueError:
        print("You need to enter integers and seperate by (',')")
        continue
```